# Как передать сгенерированную переменную?

Tags: php

Привет всем. Есть

```
class GenID 
{

        public function generationID()
        {
            $chars="qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp1234567890QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP"; 
            $max=10; 
            $size=StrLen($chars)-1; 
            $password=null; 
            while($max--) 
                $password.=$chars[rand(0,$size)];

            return $password;
        }

}
```

В нем я генерирую ID и вывожу его в index.html. В index.html есть форма в которой есть кнопка, становится активной через 5 секунд. Нажимаю на нее и перехожу в verif.php. Нужно что бы данный id передался в verif.php и что бы далее я мог его проверить. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Самое просто, хранить значение в сессии. Затем в скрипте `verif.php` проверять ее.